# x86 with COM Interop Compiled on x64

Tags: c#, com, interop, com-interop

I have a small application that I wrote that imports both the iTunes and MediaMonkey COM interfaces.  The app is developed and built on my laptop with is x64 but run on my media PC which is x86.  It runs perfectly fine on the x64 machine, but when I try to run it on the x86 media PC it fails to load.  If I disable the MediaMonkey part it works fine with iTunes, but I cannot get it to work with the MediaMonkey COM enabled.

The application is compiled for .NET framework 4.0 and as x86 specifically.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Here's a list of the problems:
1. COM
2. COM
3. COM

Comment: TRUST ME... I would not be using COM if I didn't have to.. but that's the only interface they have  :(

Comment: I know I've been there.... I feel your pain.

Comment: Does it give you a COMException at runtime or bad Win32 app? You might want to check that the COM .dll (if you're using one) is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Looks like bad app... a CLR20r3 error, apparently. How do I check if the DLL is 32 or 64?

Comment: Wait...checked the event log. Looks like it was a COMException.

Comment: Can you get the inner exception message for the COMException? That should tell you. It might be the value of an HRESULT so I would suggest taking the HRESULT number and looking for it's meaning as those are very cryptic.

Comment: HRESULT is REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG, "Class not registered"

Comment: Open a run prompt, type in regsvr32 <path to the DLL for MediaMoneky COM> and then run it again

Comment: see...that's the weird thing. Can't find it.  When I add the reference in visual studio, it is to MediaMonkey.exe, but then it seems to extract the COM DLL.... I cannot find this DLL by itself on the x86 computer anywhere.  And I tried copying it over and registering it, but it says that it has no valid entry point :(

Comment: In visual studio it says the reference type is ActiveX

Comment: 0_0 that's weird... normally you don't hook the .exe as a COM interface it's a .dll, are you sure that you can't find a .dll for the MediaMonkey COM interface?

Comment: positive :( iTunes is the same exact way, you reference iTunes.exe and it gives you Interop.iTunesLib.dll

Comment: See here: http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Introduction_to_scripting#About_external_scripts_and_applications

Comment: tried that... just returned and launched MediaMonkey

Comment: does your application run though? try restarting and trying again since registering sometimes takes effect after restart

Comment: actually... correction, when I run regsvr32 on the exe it fails with the same DLL entry point error as the DLL

Comment: try building it on the laptop, it may be that visual studio uses MSBind to register the COM component for you IIRC

Comment: I've been building it on the laptop all along. (I do not have an x86 only machine to build it on). What is the implication of it using MSBind?

Comment: That it registers the COM component so you don't have to. Can't really think of why it wouldnt' run unless the .exe itself is 64 bit only.

Comment: yeah...that's what's confusing. MM is 32 bit only.  And I don't really get why the COM component would not be registered on my other machine.  To make things weirder, it does work on my other x64 desktop that has no development tools on it, so the COM dll would not have been loaded via Visual Studio... which brings me back to thinking it is due to it being on x86... so confused :P

Comment: I know of errors between 32 and 64 bit but not registering errors (passing certain structs and such from 64 to 32 bit and vice versa gives memory errors because the sizes are different), I'm out of ideas lol

Comment: @Adam, have you tried to reinstall MM on you media PC, using "run as administrator" for the installation? There's a somewhat dated discussion in MM forums - [Installer doesn't install COM Object properly](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=45530). Also, note that ActiveX servers don't have to be DLLs - [they can be EXEs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297279).

Comment: What does CORFLAGS say about whether the interop assembly is x86 or x64 or AnyCPU?

Comment: @eran - THANK YOU!!!!! When I installed MM I told it NOT to start it after install because I had to modify the config to used a shared library on the network.  I just ran it once as admin and it worked right away! Throw a "real" answer up below this and I'll mark it as the official answer.

Comment: @Jesus - BTW, even though we never reached the solution, thank you for all your help.  I know far more about COM now than I ever did before.

Comment: @Adam no problem guess the simple "reinstall" procedure works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the lengthy comments conversation, here's my suggestion as a real answer:

Try to reinstall MM on you media PC, using "run as administrator" for the installation. There's a somewhat dated discussion in MM forums - [Installer doesn't install COM Object properly](http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=45530). If the MM COM server was not registered properly, it will not be available.

Also, I don't know if this is relevant for this case, but FWIW - there might not be a DLL to register. ActiveX EXEs can use the default marshaller, without a need for a proxy-stub, and can be [registered directly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297279).

Comment: Correct, there was no DLL to be found. Visual Studio seemed to just be generating an interop DLL for me.  Also, I actually didn't have to reinstall... I just browsed to the MM folder, right clicked on the EXE and chose run as administrator.  I let it open, closed it and then reopened normally.  After doing so, my app worked like a charm.  Thanks again! That was driving me crazy...

Comment: @Adam, I don't know how MM works, but I imagine it registers itself as a COM server when it is run. This merely means creating some registry entries. By convention it is done by invoking DLLRegisterServer or when an EXE recognizes the -RegServer switch was used, but that can easily be done when running the EXE as usual. So it still counts as installation from the COM point of view... :) Anyway, I'm happy this worked out for you.